# Cannot use Spring's JSP libraries

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I want to user Spring's JSP libraries in my jsp file, see my jsp page code below:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglig prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"  %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Register</h1>
<sf:form method="POST" commandName="spitter">
User ID: <sf:input  path="id" /><sf:errors path="id" />   <br />
First Name: <sf:input  path="firstName" /><sf:errors path="firstName" />  <br/>
Last Name: <sf:input  path="lastName" /><sf:errors path="lastName" /> <br/>
Password: <sf:input  path="password" /><sf:errors path="password" /> <br/>

<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</sf:form>
</body>
</html>
```

in the build time, I get a warning message like this:
[image]

and when I run to this page, I got 500 error:

[image]

I think this is related to the tablib, but I don't know what's the problem and how to fix it, can someone tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be <%@ **taglib** prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%> instead of <%@ **taglig** prefix="sf"